# How do I use D3 with JavaScript events

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Am trying to draw d3 charts when a button is clicked.
But all the d3 tutorials I've seen says the d3 code should be placed inside the element
you want the charts to appear. This means the d3 code will execute when the page loads but I
want the code to run only when a button is clicked.

I also want to know if I can place my d3 code in an external file wrapped in a function 
that I can call when I want to. If no, how do i create button that will show a d3 chart when clicked?

HTML

```
<input type="button" Value="show" />

<div id="presentation">
<!-- bar charts to show up here when the "show" button is clicked.
     The button makes an ajax call and gets a json that contains data
     that will be used to draw the chart.
 -->
</div>
```

Comment: *"I also want to know if I can place my d3 code in an external file wrapped in a function that I can call when I want to."* Yes you can do that and that's exactly what you *should* do. The D3 examples are loaded on page load because the user shouldn't have to do anything else to show the example. Your use case is different, so you put the code in a function and call on button click. That's perfectly fine!

Comment: Indeed! It works. Stupid me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/rUtS5/

Edit CSS first

```
#presentation {
   ...
   display: none;
}
```

Then add a blank class on your buttons

```
<input type="button" Value="show" class="example" />
```

Use jQuery

```
<script>
     $(".example").click(function () {
         $('#presentation').fadeIn("slow");
     });
</script>
```

Result:

presentation div will not be seen when the page load. When someone click the button which has example class it will be seen.

You can also use **toggle()**, **slideToggle()** or **fadeToggle()** functions instead **fadeIn()** for show/hide property.

I hope it helps... :/

---

P.S. If you try this solution

add this code in `<head>` section

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

and use jQuery codes at the bottom of page before `</body>`

Comment: What makes you think the OP uses jQuery?